# Mocking HttpServerUtilityBase

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, rhino

I can't seem to Mock HttpServerUtilityBase using Rhino Mocks.

```
_mocks = new MockRepository();
_mockHttpContext = _mocks.DynamicMock<HttpContextBase>();
_mockHttpUtilityBase = _mocks.Stub<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
_mockHttpContext.Stub(c => c.Server).Return(_mockHttpUtilityBase);

var Server  = _mockHttpContext.Server;
```

But server is set to Null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in an HTTP Context? Otherwise, c.Server makes no sense, and is therefore null.

Comment: Sorry. Updated the code. 

Not running in HttpContext but I was expecting to stub out the call to return my mockHttpUtilityBase object

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the properties of the mocked object `_mockHttpUtilityBase` to the Mocked `HttpContextBase`. To do so, replace line 4 with the following:

```
_mockHttpContext.Stub(c => c.Server).Return(_mockHttpUtilityBase.object);
```